# LibreOffice - Silent Crash on 4.1.1.2

Tags: kubuntu, libreoffice

Just installed (a few days ago) the latest update to LibreOffice, being Version: 4.1.1.2 [Build ID: 410m0(Build:2)].
Kubuntu version is Raring.
Source was the LO ppa on launchpad.  Installed fine with no error msgs.

Did not have this problem prior to the latest update.

Not clear whether its a LO packaging problem, a LO problem or a problem on my laptop.

I am now getting silent crashes, mainly (or always?) upon trying to "Save As" LO files (using KDE dialogs).
Typically when trying to select or change a filename. Major PITA as its hard to save your work before a crash!

Is anyone else having the same problem?

Thanks

Andy

--

Just had another silent crash with a particular file. Unfortunately, had not started it in a terminal (started via KDE menus).
Tried to reproduce error, using same file, doing the same procedure (Save As), starting LO in a terminal.  Result: no crash but got the following output in terminal:

```
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/hp______DVDRAM_GT31L_KZMB1575539" : property 
"Drive" does not exist 
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/WDC_WD7500BPKT_00PK4T0_WD_WXD1A11V3246" : 
property "Drive" does not exist 
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/WDC_WD7500BPKT_00PK4T0_WD_WXD1A11V3246" : 
property "DeviceNumber" does not exist 
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/WDC_WD7500BPKT_00PK4T0_WD_WXD1A11V3246" : 
property "Device" does not exist 
LibreOffice(8333): couldn't create slave: "Unable to create io-slave:
klauncher said: Unknown protocol ''.
" 
X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Major opcode: 42 (X_SetInputFocus)
  Resource id:  0x5e02b43
X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Major opcode: 42 (X_SetInputFocus)
  Resource id:  0x5e02b43
```

Comment: Could you try running LO in a terminal please? That way you will be able to post the crash output here.

Comment: Updated original question with some terminal output above, as requested.

Comment: I now have a backtrace from gbd, as no terminal output appeared. The first line indicates that its a KDE error? 
Can someone please explain how do I add it to this form please?

Answer (score 1):

I had also had the error in Kubuntu 13.10 with libreoffice 4.1.3:

```
X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
  Major opcode: 42 (X_SetInputFocus)
  Resource id:  0x5e02b43
```

It used to appear intermittently on drawing certain dialog boxes, and especially when zotero integration plugin tried to open its box.

I solved the problem by uninstalling the KDE integration and replacing it with the GTK one.

```
sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-kde libreoffice-style-oxygen
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-style-human
```

HTH !